# Airflow how to catch up on hourly basis

Tags: python, airflow, vertica

I have a dag that collects data at hourly basis without catchup. Now I'd like to catch up from say June 1st:

```py
dag = DAG(dag_id='test',
          start_date=datetime(2021, 6, 1),
          description='Airflow Test Run',
          schedule_interval="15 0 * * *",   # Hourly at minute 15
          max_active_runs=1,
          catchup=True,
          default_args=default_args
          )
```

And the Vertica SQL involved (inital version for `catchup=False`):

```
INSERT INTO table1
SELECT * FROM table2 
WHERE
    -- it means "Load data from last hour"
    eventTimestamp >= DATE_TRUNC('HOUR', NOW()) - interval '1 hour'
    AND eventTimestamp < DATE_TRUNC('HOUR', NOW())
```

The document indicates that:

> An Airflow DAG with a start_date, possibly an end_date, and a schedule_interval defines a series of intervals which the scheduler turns into individual DAG Runs and executes. The scheduler, by default, will kick off a DAG Run for any interval that has not been run since the last execution date (or has been cleared). This concept is called Catchup.

However, I don't know how to write the SQL query that satisfies this. I know that I can pass `execute_date` to the query, but this is not daily catch up, but hourly catchup. AFAIK we don't have something like an `execution_hour`.

How can I achieve this without much hack? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should use `ts` airflow macro instead of using NOW() functions. With this macro, you always rerun the DAG at the exact execution date of airflow. You can read more about macros of airflow [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/macros-ref.html).

Second, to backfill data from June 1st, you can use this SQL

```
INSERT INTO table1
SELECT * FROM table2 
WHERE
    eventTimestamp >= TIMESTAMP '2021-06-01 00:00:00' 
    AND eventTimestamp < TIMESTAMP [the timestamp which you already have data]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `catchup=False` with Airflow [macros](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/macros-ref.html) that are relevant for your use case.

I believe what you are looking for is:

```
WHERE eventTimestamp >= {{ execution_date }} AND {{ next_execution_date }}
```

This means the following:
In that run that will start on `2021-06-30 04:00` (with execution date of `2021-06-30 03:00` ) the query will be:

```
WHERE eventTimestamp >= '2021-06-30 03:00' AND '2021-06-30 04:00'
```

Using `execution_date` with `catchup=False` means that in case of downtime of 3 hours - once Airflow is back it will schedule 3 runs - each on of the runs will process 1 hour of data (just like it would if there was no down time at all)

Note that you can change the format of the timestamp as required by the DB that you are using.

`{{ execution_date }}` will give you `2021-06-30T07:30:16.365941+00:00`

`{{ execution_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] }}` will give `2021-06-29 07:30:16.365`